# SQL substring of URL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, substring

I am trying to select a part of a `url` which is after a wildcard expression and before another expression using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I have a url like:

```
https%www.msn.com%2ftokenauth%mapserver%ftoken%aogvgkooo%json
```

or:

```
https%www.msn.com%2ftokenauth%mapserver%token=aogvgkooo%json.
```

How do I write a `sql` query to only show `aogvgkooo`? The `url` is stored in column called `url`.

Here is my select statement:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(url, 'token=', ''),'%json', '')
```

Comment: @juergend - I guess I'd better learn how to read!

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX or PATINDEX functions? this site gives a good explanation of them:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

and this one gives an example as well

http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/u.cgi/tip238311/sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @url varchar(100)

SET @url ='https%www.msn.com%2ftokenauth%mapserver%token=aogvgkooo%json'

SELECT Replace(Replace(Replace(@url,substring(@url,1,Patindex('%token=%',@url)-1),''),'token=',''),'%json','')
```

[sql fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7caf1/8)

Comment: I try and run it and SQL says Invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function.

Comment: Look at the sql fiddler link I included. It shows that, the sql runs.

Answer (score 0):

A user-defined function might be a good choice.

```
create function findToken (
  @url nvarchar(max),
  @tag nvarchar(100),
  @after nvarchar(100)
) returns nvarchar(max) as begin
    declare @token nvarchar(max);
    declare @start int = charindex(@tag,@url) + len(@tag);
    declare @justPast int = charindex(@after,@url,@start);
    if @start = len(@tag) or @justPast = 0
      return NULL;
    return substring(@url,@start,@justPast-@start)
end;
go

declare @url varchar(100);

set @url ='https%www.msn.com%2ftokenauth%mapserver%token=aogvgkooo%json';

select
  dbo.findToken(@url,'token=','%json');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @url nvarchar(255),
        @startPos nvarchar(100),
        @endPos nvarchar(100)

SET @url ='https%www.msn.com%2ftokenauth%mapserver%token=aogvgkooo%json'
SET @startPos = 'token%'
SET @endPos = '%json'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@url,CHARINDEX(@startPos,REPLACE (@url,'=','%'),0)+ LEN(@startPos) ,CHARINDEX(@endPos,REPLACE (@url,'=','%'),0)-(CHARINDEX(@startPos,REPLACE (@url,'=','%'),0)+ LEN(@startPos)))
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: We take URL, find the place where @startPos ends
`CHARINDEX(@startPos,REPLACE (@url,'=','%'),0)+ LEN(@startPos)`
that is the start of part that we need

Then we search for first occurance of @endPos
`CHARINDEX(@endPos,REPLACE (@url,'=','%'),0)`
and substract start possition from the part above

Answer (score 0):

More general approach:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = 'https%www.msn.com%2ftokenauth%mapserver%ftoken%aogvgkooo%json'

SELECT  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
                            REVERSE(@s), 
                            CHARINDEX('%', REVERSE(@s)) + 1,
                            CHARINDEX('%', REVERSE(@s),  CHARINDEX('%', REVERSE(@s)) + 1) -
                                                         CHARINDEX('%', REVERSE(@s)) - 1))
```

Reversing string, then take `substring` from first occurence of `%` till second occurence, then reversing again.